# Error Page Expired and can't take value from textarea

Tags: php, laravel

I have a view lesson.blade.php like this

```php
@extends('master')
@section('content')
<form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal form-simple">
    <div class="lesson content-wrapper">
        <div class="content-header row">
            <div class="content-header-left col-md-6 col-xs-12 mb-1">
                <h4 class="content-header-title"><a href="#"> Bài giảng </a></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content-body">
            <div class="lesson-left col-md-8">
                <div class="card border-grey border-lighten-3 px-2 py-2 m-0 box-shadow-1">
                    <textarea class="lesson-title" rows="1" placeholder="Thêm tiêu đề" name="title"></textarea>
                    <textarea class="lesson-content" rows="1" placeholder="Thêm nội dung" name="content"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="lesson-right col-md-4">
                <div class="card border-grey border-lighten-3 px-2 py-2 box-shadow-1">
                    <h4 class="content-header-title">Video</h4>
                    <input type="file" name="video">
                </div>

                <div class="card border-grey border-lighten-3 px-2 py-2 box-shadow-1 mt-1">
                    <h4 class="content-header-title"> Tags </h4>
                    <select name="tag_id" id="tags" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
                        @foreach($tags as $key=>$value)
                        <option value="{{$key}}">{{$value}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="card border-grey border-lighten-3 px-2 py-2 box-shadow-1 mt-1">
                    <h4 class="content-header-title">Khóa học</h4>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input ml-0" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
                            Default checkbox
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input ml-0" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck2">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck2">
                            Disabled checkbox
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <row>
                    <div class="col-md-6 pl-0">
                        <button class="btn btn-basic">Close</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 pr-0">
                        <button class="btn btn-success" formaction="{{route('saveLess')}}">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </row>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
@endsection
```

i have two trouble. The first is button 'Save', when i click to button 'Save',  it appears an error

> 419 | Page Expired

And the second trouble is my LessonController, i can't get value form textarea name="title" and name="content".

LessonController

```php
    function saveLess(Request $req){
            dd($req->title);
            $post = new Post;
            $post->title    = $req->title;
            $post->content  = $req->content;
            $post->save();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `CSRF` token when using a `POST` method.

```
<form action="{{route('your.route)}}" method="post" class="form-horizontal form-simple">
    @csrf
    //rest of the form
```

Your text area fields look fine. You can check whether you get the values in controller by `dd($req)`

Comment: yep, the csrf token was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Please add csrf token.

```
   <form method="POST" action="/profile">
     @csrf
    ...
   </form>
```

Comment: Well, you can also use {{csrf_token}} according to your php version

Answer (score 0):

Please pass csrf token in your form